# Creating sub-algorithms

Tags: algorithms

I want to have two algorithms together that I can refer to as 1a and 1b (rather than seperately as Algorithm 1 and 2).
So very similar to how subfigures work.

Is this possible using any of the available algorithm packages?

(NOTE: I did notice this thread [Creating sub-algorithms in latex using the algorithm package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66317/creating-sub-algorithms-in-latex-using-the-algorithm-package) but that is not what I mean).